# Macro gives problems in gcc

Tags: c++, macros, byte

```
#include<vector>
#include<stdint.h>
#define RAM_M_V_INSERT_T32(vec,Long,pos) \
vec.at(pos)=(((tU8)((Long) >> 24)) & 0xFF); \
pos++;\
vec.at(pos)=(((tU8)((Long) >> 16)) & 0xFF); \
pos++;\
vec.at(pos)=(((tU8)((Long) >> 8)) & 0xFF); \
pos++;\
vec.at(pos)=(((tU8)((Long))) & 0xFF);

int main()
{  
std::vector<char> c8vBuf;
c8vBuf.at(0)=(char)SYSTEM_U32_SHUTDOWN_CPU_WATCHDOG;
RAM_M_V_INSERT_T32(c8vBuf, (_u32WdtCount - 1),1);
RAM_M_V_INSERT_T32(c8vBuf, _u32WdtCount,5);
return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error,related to increment operand

```
cstr.cpp:19:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
cstr.cpp:19:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
cstr.cpp:19:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
cstr.cpp:20:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
cstr.cpp:20:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
cstr.cpp:20:3: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

Anyone please shed light on this???

Comment: What do you expect 1++ and 5++ to do?

Comment: Was there a compiler that allowed the use of the macro, or is the fact that you're using GCC just the specific compiler and you've not tested the code on other compilers?

Comment: You can (and should) run your compiler to only evoke the preprocessor, and inspect the code produced.  It can be enlightening.

Comment: Hi,Guys thanks for the replies....I can understand the error now...I overcame it by passing an integer variable instead of a value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros will essentially perform a text replacement that happens via the pre-processor.

The macro will turn your code into something like `1++` and `5++`. These are integer literals, which means the compiler marks them as 'pure' rvalues (prvalues). prvalues are not the same as l-values

Answer (score 2):

Given that you apply a `++` operator to the `pos` argument, you cannot pass a constant like 1 or 5 as the third argument to the macro.  Any compiler that let you do that would be erroneous.